# How can I make this Javascript code responsive for any screen?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying, with no success, to make this code responsive. The autozize keeps making the chart too flat and if I use height and width it justs works for some screens.

any ideas?

**with Height and Width**

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new TradingView.widget({
"width": 800,
"height": 600,
"symbol": "INDEX:MERV",
"interval": "D",
"timezone": "Etc/UTC",
"theme": "White",
"style": "1",
"locale": "es",
"toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
"enable_publishing": false,
"allow_symbol_change": true,
"hideideas": true,
"show_popup_button": true,
"popup_width": "1000",
"popup_height": "650"
});
</script>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

**with autosize**

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<script     type="text/javascript"
src="https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new TradingView.widget({
"autosize": true,
"symbol": "INDEX:MERV",
"interval": "D",
"timezone": "Etc/UTC",
"theme": "White",
"style": "1",
"locale": "es",
"toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
"enable_publishing": false,
"allow_symbol_change": true,
"hideideas": true,
"show_popup_button": true,
"popup_width": "1000",
"popup_height": "650"
});
 </script>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Thaks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use autosize but try to put your chart in a container with a defined max-width and max-height (or define différent width/height according to media-queries).